# MS Office for Mac 2011 Add-Ins development

Tags: macos, ms-office, add-in

I would like to develop Add-in for office for Mac 2011. But I cannot find any manuals about Add-Ins development.
Does anybody know how to develop Add-Ins for Office for Mac?